# Why do I see an "incompatible type" error when trying to sort this NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to sort an NSMutableArray of NSStrings.  All tutorials I've found said the same thing, but when I try to follow them I'm seeing a compile-time error. My code is as follows:

```
NSArray *sorted=[self.expressions sortUsingComparator:@selector(compare:)];
```

The compile error I see is as follows:

[image: code printscreen]

Why do I see this "Sending 'SEL' to parameter of incompatible type" error and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Also, Xcode != NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you call `sortUsingComparator` which takes NOT a selector BUT a comparator block

you want to call `sortUsingSelector:` -- which calls the Selector you pass (compare:) for each comparison